# New Session in new tab

Tags: asp.net, session

Iam working on Asp.net1.1 application... i want to implement one thing in my application...
When iam browsing application in between that if i copy app Url & paste it into same browser but into new tab,then it should redirect to login page...means session should not get continue ...so how to implement this ...?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at these two SO questions already discussed previously:

[How in ASP.NET, do you deal with session and multiple tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447681/how-in-asp-net-do-you-deal-with-session-and-multiple-tabs)

[How to differ sessions in browser-tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs)